HTML video playsinline media query bug? Is there away around this?
I'm working with responsive videos, and running into an issue.  On most browsers, this is working as expected.  On page load the appropriate video size is selected.
On Safari however, I'm running into an issue.  Often times on the first load, the media query is being skipped over. Eventually after enough refreshes it will correct itself.  If I remove the "playsinline" though, it suddenly seems to work in a new session.
I've been up and down Google, but I can't seem to find any insight on this behavior.  Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?  Or maybe if there's a way I can get this to work without offloading the responsive behavior to JS?
<video autoplay playsinline loop muted>
           <source media="(max-width: 767px)" src="https://videos.pexels.com/video-files/8508072/8508072-hd_1080_1920_25fps.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
           <source id="js-video-banner-video" src="https://videos.pexels.com/video-files/27591301/12177940_2560_1440_60fps.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

At this point I can safely say it's not the value of the media query itself.  It does work sometimes, and it works in other browsers.  I've also tried blowing the max-width up to 30000px, where it should always hit.  Even then I'm seeing this behavior.  playsinline seems to be the only attribute I can remove to make it work.
